# Regression Coefficients Interpretation - How much do we use it?

Tags: data-science, logistic-regression, coefficients

This is not a technical question, just trying to seek some feedback and insights from professional data scientists and practitioners. The majority of the sample projects I have seen floating around on the internet mainly focus on the prediction power (for example, in case of classification problems) of the developed models. This has been my general perception of the data science projects as I haven't seen that much discussion about the interpretation of the individual coefficients, while there is value in that, too.

That being said, my questions are:

- Is my perception correct at all?
- Do we mostly ignore the coefficients and their interpretation and mainly focus on the prediction power?

I appreciate sharing your thoughts on this.

Comment: regarding this question, I suggest you to read [this paper](http://www2.math.uu.se/~thulin/mm/breiman.pdf)

Comment: Great paper, thanks for sharing!